# dynamic strct array inside a dynamic stuct

Tags: c, struct, dynamic, dynamic-memory-allocation

Im trying to create an array of struct (titre) inside another structure (resultats). I also need to make the array dynamic so I can add stuff or remove stuff from it.

I tried A LOT of things and still looking for a solution.

The problem is within the function "add_title_to_result" I'm trying to dynamically set an array of the struct titre within the struct resultat.

Thx for the help!

```
struct titre {
    char* tconst;
    int start_year;
};

typedef struct titre* t_titre;

struct resultats {
    int nb_titre;
    t_titre *tab_titre;
};

typedef struct resultats* t_resultats;

//fucntion used to dynamically create a t_resultat
t_resultats creer_resultats(void) {
    t_resultats resultats_temp = (t_resultats)malloc(sizeof(struct resultats));

    assert(resultats_temp);

    resultats_temp->nb_titre = 0;
    resultats_temp->tab_titre = NULL;

    return resultats_temp;
}

void add_title_to_result(const t_titre titre_temp, t_resultats resultats) {
    if(resultats->nb_titre == 0)
    {
        resultats->tab_titre = malloc(sizeof(t_titre));
        resultats->tab_titre[resultats->nb_titre] =   malloc(sizeof(struct titre));
    }
    else
    {
        resultats->tab_titre = realloc(resultats->tab_titre, (resultats->nb_titre +1)* sizeof(t_titre));
        resultats->tab_titre[resultats->nb_titre] =malloc(sizeof(struct titre));

    }
    set_tconst(resultats->tab_titre[resultats->nb_titre], titre_temp->tconst);
}
```

Comment: Don't hide pointers with `typedef`s. You hurt people's brains.

Comment: "nothing works" is not a sufficient problem description. Please describe a specific error, incorrect behaviour or ask a specific question. Show complete code as a [mre] and describe what specific issue/error it has.

Comment: @Eric Malouin - Why do you use an array of pointers to `struct titre` rather than an array of `struct titre`s?